# How can a file be missing from SVN repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We are using TortoiseSVN for version controlling in my office.

Yesterday I committed few new files to the repository. After my commit I asked my teammate to take update and build solution. He was able to build it. 
After a few more check in. I left for the day. In next morning one of the teammate inform me that a file is missing from repo due to which he is not able to build, and ask me to commit it.

I checked my working copy. It was showing file as commuted I take update. It removed file from my working copy. I checked SVN log, it shows I have never committed that file.

How it is possible? I mean:

1. If I have not committed it how can some other teammate take update
   and build?
2. Why file was removed from my working copy if it was not
   under version control?

   Or How can a file be missing from SVN log?

Comment: Could you please make this question better readable by adding paragraphs (empty lines between logical sections) to improve its structure?

Comment: Please try to make your question clearer

Answer (score 0):

> In next morning one of the teammate inform me that a file is missing
>   from repo due to which he is not able to build, and ask me to commit
>   it.

That is impossible. If you actually committed the changes as a new revision, the revision is immutable and **is** in the repository. Use [`svn log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) or [TortoiseSVN's show log command](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html) to see the history of changes in the repository.

There is a chance that your colleague is simply looking at the wrong place, e.g. different branch or shelve. There is another possible reason -- an administrator removed or corrupted the repository and recovered an outdated backup. That's an administrator's fault in this case.